# I want to load a static file from django template like.. {% static {{post.image}} %}

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-media

I want to load a static file from django template like.. `{% static {{post.image}} %}` but is error
Can you show me code like this?

Did you understand? Need more clarification?

Comment: `post.image` this looks to be a _media_ file instead of a static file. So you should simply write `{{ post.image.url }}` no need for the `static` tag.

Comment: like `<img src="{{post.image.url}}">` it's error

Comment: error code: `Not Found: /note/static/note/test.png
[13/May/2021 14:25:21] "GET /note/static/note/test.png HTTP/1.1" 404 2357`

Comment: file in the `project/note/static/note/test.png`

Comment: Welcome to SO! You might have some luck if you post the exact error you are having in your question.